# Chrome not playing audio files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-audio

I'm having trouble getting chrome to play the audio files on this website: http://pyramids-tapes.com/

I'm using this plugin, whose demo is working in chrome: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/07/12/old-school-cassette-player-with-html5-audio/

From looking at my network tab, I'm seeing that the server is returning a 206 partial content status for the mp3 file, but I'm not sure what is causing this, visiting the file directly in the browser plays the file fine (http://pyramids-tapes.com/songs/never_satisfied.mp3).

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Author marked that this player plugin is more for fun. It has some interface caveeats, for example it suppose that music comes from local folder songs. I deployed package to localhost and put your mp3 to that folder, then changed name in cassete.js. It works. It works even with remote source (i.e. your full link to mp3), but you need to provide full path and remove full path generation from $.Song constructor. Server says 206 status indeed, but it's ok, it starts to download in short. BTW, player looks really great :)